# searchTwitter() R function not working as expected

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to pull in tweets that feature the words "Deacs" and "basketball" for the time range 11/15/15 - 11/30/15.

As the below Twitter website search reveals, such tweets certainly exist: 
https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&q=Deacs%20basketball%20since%3A2015-11-15%20until%3A2015-11-30

I have set up the TwitteR package on my environment and have successfully pulled in 1000+ tweets in the past for a call. However, when I run the following code:

```
Dtweets1 <- searchTwitter('deacs+basketball', n = 10, since = '2015-11-15', until = '2015-11-30')
```

I get the following error, and a List of 0:

```
Warning message:

In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :  10 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

Is there a particular reason this error is popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the way you are fetching the data.

Actually, the `Twitter Search API` only returns a sample of results, not the comprehensive search.

For better results, you can use Twitter Stream API, create a database of the search results, continuously update them.

Worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're searching for the literal 'deacs+basketball'. Replace '+' with a space.

Comment: `?searchTwitter` says `Use "+" to separate query terms.` and gives an example `searchTwitter('world cup+brazil', resultType="popular", n=15)`. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I found this in the documentation for GET search/tweets: "Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week."